# Include .PHP File into 2 DIVs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am using wordpress to create a custom theme.

I want to put all of the content in my slider.php

Into a div box found in my index.php

How do I do this?

**SLIDER.PHP**

```
<div class="slider">
<img id="1" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/001.png" />
<img id="2" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/002.png" />
<img id="3" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/003.png" />
<img id="4" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/004.png" />
<img id="5" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/005.png" />
<img id="6" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/006.png" />
<img id="7" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/007.png" />
<img id="8" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/008.png" />
<img id="9" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/009.png" />
<img id="10" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/010.png" />
<img id="11" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/011.png" />
<img id="12" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/012.png" />
<img id="13" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/013.png" />
<img id="14" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/014.png" />
<img id="15" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/015.png" />
<img id="16" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/016.png" />
<img id="17" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/017.png" />
<img id="18" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/018.png" />
<img id="19" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/019.png" />
<img id="20" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/020.png" />
<img id="21" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/021.png" />
<img id="22" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/022.png" />
<img id="23" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/023.png" />
<img id="24" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/024.png" />
<img id="25" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/025.png" />
<img id="26" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/026.png" />
<img id="27" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/027.png" />
<img id="28" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/028.png" />
<img id="29" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/029.png" />
<img id="30" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/030.png" />
<img id="31" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/031.png" />
<img id="32" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/032.png" />
<img id="33" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/033.png" />
<img id="34" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/034.png" />
<img id="35" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/035.png" />
<img id="36" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/036.png" />
<img id="37" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/037.png" />
<img id="38" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/038.png" />
<img id="39" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/039.png" />
<img id="40" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/040.png" />
<img id="41" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/041.png" />
<img id="42" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/042.png" />
<img id="43" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/043.png" />
<img id="44" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/044.png" />
<img id="45" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/045.png" />
<img id="46" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/046.png" />
<img id="47" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/047.png" />
<img id="48" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/048.png" />
<img id="49" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/049.png" />
<img id="50" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/050.png" />
<img id="61" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/061.png" />
<img id="62" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/062.png" />
<img id="63" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/063.png" />
<img id="64" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/064.png" />
<img id="65" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/065.png" />
<img id="66" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/066.png" />
<img id="67" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/067.png" />
<img id="68" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/068.png" />
<img id="69" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/069.png" />
<img id="70" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/070.png" />
<img id="71" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/071.png" />
<img id="72" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/072.png" />
<img id="73" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/073.png" />
<img id="74" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/074.png" />
<img id="75" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/075.png" />
<img id="76" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/076.png" />
<img id="77" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/077.png" />
<img id="78" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/078.png" />
<img id="79" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/079.png" />
<img id="80" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/080.png" />
<img id="81" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/081.png" />
<img id="82" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/082.png" />
<img id="83" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/083.png" />
<img id="84" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/084.png" />
<img id="85" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/085.png" />
<img id="86" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/086.png" />
<img id="87" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/087.png" />
<img id="88" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/088.png" />
<img id="89" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/089.png" />
<img id="90" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/090.png" />
<img id="91" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/091.png" />
<img id="92" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/092.png" />
<img id="93" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/093.png" />
<img id="94" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/094.png" />
<img id="95" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/095.png" />
<img id="96" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/096.png" />
<img id="97" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/097.png" />
<img id="98" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/098.png" />
<img id="99" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/099.png" />
<img id="100" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/Pokemon/100.png" />
<img id="101" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/101.png" />
<img id="102" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/102.png" />
<img id="103" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/103.png" />
<img id="104" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/104.png" />
<img id="105" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/105.png" />
<img id="106" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/106.png" />
<img id="107" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/107.png" />
<img id="108" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/108.png" />
<img id="109" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/109.png" />
<img id="110" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/110.png" />
<img id="111" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/111.png" />
<img id="112" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/112.png" />
<img id="113" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/113.png" />
<img id="114" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/114.png" />
<img id="115" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/115.png" />
<img id="116" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/116.png" />
<img id="117" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/117.png" />
<img id="118" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/118.png" />
<img id="119" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/119.png" />
<img id="120" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/120.png" />
<img id="121" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/121.png" />
<img id="122" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/122.png" />
<img id="123" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/123.png" />
<img id="124" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/124.png" />
<img id="125" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/125.png" />
<img id="126" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/126.png" />
<img id="127" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/127.png" />
<img id="128" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/128.png" />
<img id="129" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/129.png" />
<img id="130" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/130.png" />
<img id="131" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/131.png" />
<img id="132" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/132.png" />
<img id="133" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/133.png" />
<img id="134" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/134.png" />
<img id="135" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/135.png" />
<img id="136" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/136.png" />
<img id="137" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/137.png" />
<img id="138" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/138.png" />
<img id="139" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/139.png" />
<img id="140" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/140.png" />
<img id="141" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/141.png" />
<img id="142" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/142.png" />
<img id="143" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/143.png" />
<img id="144" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/144.png" />
<img id="145" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/145.png" />
<img id="146" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/146.png" />
<img id="147" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/147.png" />
<img id="148" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/148.png" />
<img id="149" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/149.png" />
<img id="150" src="http://www.gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/images/pokemon/150.png" />
</div>
```

I want ALL of that code

Copy and pasted

Inside the DIV "#SliderMobile"

And

Inside the DIV "#SliderPC"

Both DIVS are located in INDEX.PHP

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<div class="#SliderMobile"><?php include('slider.php'); ?></div>
<div class="#SliderPC"><?php include('slider.php'); ?></div>
```

How do I do this?

---

EDIT:

I tried using

```
<?php include('slider.php'); ?>
```

It works if I use it ONCE

But

It does NOT work if I Use it TWICE

How do I include slider.php content MORE THAN TWICE?

(In Multiple DIVs in index.php) ?

---

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this information is useful

But

Here is Javascript for my Slider Script Code

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {

//$('.slider #1').show({right:'0'}, 500);
$('.slider #1').show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
$('.slider #1').delay(5500).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500);

var sliderTotalImg = $('.slider img').size();    
var counterIndex = 2;
var slidecount=150;

setInterval(function () {

    //$('.slider #' + counterIndex).show({right:'0'}, 500);
    $('.slider #' + counterIndex).show('slide',{direction:'right'},500);
    $('.slider #' + counterIndex).delay(5500).hide('slide',{direction:'left'},500);

    if(counterIndex==slidecount){
counterIndex=1;

}else{
counterIndex++;
}
},6500);});</script>
```

---

EDIT:

This is my index.php

If you open www.gohatchmyegg.com

I want my pokemon slider to appear in both

The top left column in PC Widescreen Viewport Mode

AND

The bottom right column in Mobile Viewport Mode

Resize Window.

So I am trying to include the slider twice.

The slider.php should be included in both ".slider1" and ".slider2" DIV Boxes

**INDEX.PHP**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:768px) and
(max-width:980px)" href="http://gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/css/style_large.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:600px) and
(max-width:767px)" href="http://gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/css/style_medium.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:200px) and
(max-width:599px)" href="http://gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/css/style_small.css">

</head>  

<div id="BodyContent">
<div id="SidebarLeft"><div id="SideBarLeftContent"><div class="slider1"><?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php'; ?>
</div></div></div><div id="MainText"><div id="MainTextBox"><div id="MainTextArticle"><?php query_posts('p=22' ); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()); ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>
<?php
echo the_content();
endwhile; ?></div></div></div><div id="SidebarRight"><div id="SideBarRightContent"><div id="RightContent"><div id="YoutubeVideo"></div>

<div id="BottomRight"><div class="slider2"><?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php'; ?>    </div></div></div></div></div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: And you have tried what so far?

Comment: so, insert it.........

Comment: Nothing that works. I don't want to copy and paste the whole thing as you see it's a lot of code to scroll through. I just want some sort of PHP Script that lets me load the slider.php into the DIVs located in the index.php.

Comment: The error you get when it only works once should give you a clue. I am guessing that it is because of the header you are inserting after the output buffer has started. Delete the 'header()' function at the top of slider, or move it to the index.php file

Comment: Does anybody know how I can use <?php include(''); ?> twice on the same page? Please? I edited the question and I added more information. I even helped answer a couple of questions. I really need help knowing how to use php include more than twice. I googled it and I found another article on stackoverflow that talked about using <?php include(''); ?>twice and they suggested using <?php include_once(''); ?> but <?php include_once(''); ?> also didn't work. I went to php.net and I couldn't find anything to make <?php include_once(''); ?> work twice on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

This always worked for me when I needed to add two of the same file.

`<?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php'; ?>`

Comment: Warning: include(/home/www/gohatchmyegg.com/slider.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /srv/disk12/1806831/www/gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/index.php on line 21

Comment: Where is the slider.php file located?

Comment: <?php include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/slider.php'; ?>

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn't include twice. www.gohatchmyegg.com. The pokemon slider should display the pokemon slide in both top left and bottom right corners but it is only including it once. BTW I Edited Original Post. Added More Information-> Index.php.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the file with php.

```
<div id="slider">
<?php include 'slider.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I got "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''http://gohatchmyegg.com/wp-co' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in /srv/disk12/1806831/www/gohatchmyegg.com/wp-content/themes/GoHatchMyEgg/index.php on line 27"

Comment: It works once but not twice.  I could only include the slider.php in ONE DIV but not the OTHER DIV. I could only include the slider.php in #SliderMobile DIV but not the #SliderPC DIV. It loads in one but not the other. Why is this happening? How can I include it inside both DIVs?

Comment: See: www.gohatchmyegg.com 

Switch from PC and Mobile

Comment: The error you get when it only works once should give you a clue. I am guessing that it is because of the header you are inserting after the output buffer has started. Delete the 'header()' function at the top of slider, or move it to the index.php file

Comment: I already deleted the 'header()' function at the top of slider.php but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I Edited The Original Post. I Added My Slider Javascript Code. Maybe this extra information can be helpful?